# How to add maven to a rails project?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, maven, jenkins

My project in rails. As CI I have - Jenkins.
Jenkins has a plugin - [Bitbucket Server Code Coverage](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master/) (plug-in for visualization of untested code)
This plugin has the ability to send data to the server using maven - [code-coverage-maven-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master/code-coverage-maven-plugin/)
I add `settings.xml` to the root of my project  (as in [инструкции](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master/code-coverage-maven-plugin/README.md))
Run: `mvn com.atlassian.bitbucket:code-coverage-maven-plugin:publish`, but the command fails with an error

```
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'com.atlassian.bitbucket:code-coverage-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (/app/?/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
```

I think to fix this I need to `settings.xml` specify the path to the repository, where to get the plugin. How can this be done?

Where it should be located `pom.xml` and `settings.xml`?
How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Why would you like to add Maven to a ruby-on-rails project?

Comment: This is required for the Jenkins plugin https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master/code-coverage-maven-plugin/

Comment: mvn will run on Jenkins

Comment: You can build ruby projects (rake?) on Jenkins as well there is no need for Maven?

Comment: yes, on Jenkins as well there is no need for Maven

Comment: So why do you use Maven? If the problem is the code coverage use an appropriate coverage tool for Ruby... ?

Comment: I need a visual representation of the code uncovered by the test. plugin https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-code-coverage/src/master does this. This plugin works with Maven. If you know a similar tool for ruby, please tell me.